# Rotating an image in MarkDown language

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to rotate images (the way the image is presented) using md languages?

I know there are ways to resize the image like `![image.jpeg|400]`, is there something like `![image.jpeg|rotate="90"]`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "I know there are ways to resize the image like `![image.jpeg|400]`"—that's not standard Markdown. What is the specific tool that you are using?

Comment: @Chris I don't remember where exactly I read about this, but this works in Obsidian

Comment: Well it's a proprietary extension. [The Obsidian docs](https://help.obsidian.md/Obsidian/Index) (assuming that's what you're referring to) don't mention anything about rotating. I suspect the answer is "no".